# exponential decay - from NLS to nlme

Tags: r, exponential, nls, nlme

I am somewhat familiar with `lme4`, but not with the `nlme` package, and I struggling to fit the mixed-effects that I desire.

I ran the following model with NLS. (Comments about the starting values are welcome too)

```
m3 <- nls(s  ~ f0 + f1 * 2^(-MINUTES / K),
          data = dat ,
          start = list(f0 = 117, f1 = 16, K = 2.5))
summary(m3)
```

**Q1** - What's the code to run the previous model with nlme, but with a random intercept for "ID"?

I tried

```
m1 <- nlme(s  ~ f0 + f1 * 2^(-MINUTES / K),
    data = dat ,
    fixed = f0 + f1 + MINUTES + K ~ 1,
    random = ID ~ 1 , 
    start = list(f0 = 117, f1 = 16, K = 2.5))
```

But gave error

> Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, eval(parse(text = paste("~1",
> deparse(groups[[2]]),  :    invalid formula for groups

**Q2** - Same as before, but also with MINUTES*group interaction?

dataframe:

```
  dat <-  structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 
45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 49, 49, 49, 49, 
49, 49, 49, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 
55, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 
57, 57, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9), MINUTES = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 
25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 
5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 
20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 
0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 
15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 
30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 
10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 
25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 
5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 
20, 25, 30, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 
0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 
15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 
30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30), group = c("fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", "fff", 
"fff", "fff"), s = c(148, 151, 142, 147, 141, 142, 145, 
131.5, 124, 114, 117, 119, 127, 119, 155.5, 110, 112, 111, 110, 
108, 110, 149.5, 128, 117, 123, 125, 124, 130, 131, 117, 119, 
125, 129, 125, 125, 147.5, 132, 117, 114, 116, 117, 115, 133, 
125, 122, 125, 127, 124, 128, 106, 120, 115, 116, 119, 113, 115, 
121, 97, 114, 99, 97, 102, 102, 133.5, 105, 104, 107, 103, 104, 
108, 131, 118, 122, 121, 127, 126, 119, 133, 129, 130, 130, 129, 
124, 126, 125, 117, 115, 116, 114, 122, 119, 137.5, 116, 111, 
117, 111, 117, 108, 124, 124, 125, 123, 119, 121, 112, 136.5, 
123, 126, 123, 119, 127, 112, 120.5, 104, 100, 107, 110, 106, 
104, 116.5, 117, 116, 117, 120, 113, 121, 149, 134, 117, 115, 
123, 117, 110, 146, 129, 131, 126, 127, 137, 128, 129.5, 105, 
119, 125, 107, 120, 120, 113, 118, 114, 109, 109, 117, 112, 120, 
110, 116, 107, 112, 111, 113, 108, 103, 105, 106, 104, 111, 123, 
84, 84, 87, 88, 81, 84, 116, 97, 107, 99, 96, 94, 104, 133, 127, 
118, 127, 123, 119, 121, 140.5, 116, 118, 116, 121, 121, 116, 
143, 138, 137, 130, 129, 119, 133, 120, 108, 98, 103, 105, 100, 
97, 130, 107, 113, 114, 111, 106, 108, 156, 137, 138, 134, 142, 
135, 145)), row.names = c(8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 
83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 
102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 
138L, 139L, 140L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 
156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 
167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 
178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 
189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 
200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 
218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 
229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 
240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 
251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 
262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 
287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 
298L, 299L, 300L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe these would be:

```r
library(nlme)
m1 <- nlme(s  ~ f0 + f1 * 2^(-MINUTES / K),
    data = dat ,
    fixed = f0 + f1 + K ~ 1,
    random = f0 ~ 1 | ID,
    start = c(f0 = 117, f1 = 16, K = 2.5))


m2 <- nlme(s  ~ f0 + f1 * 2^(-MINUTES / K),
    data = dat ,
    fixed = f0 + f1 + K ~ 1,
    random = f0 + f1 ~ 1 | ID,
    start = c(f0 = 117, f1 = 16, K = 2.5))
```

By "MINUTES*group interaction" I am assuming you only care about the magnitude (`f1`) and not the scale (`K`) of the `MINUTES` effect to vary by group: in principle `random = f0 + f1 + K ~ 1 | ID` is possible, but I ran into a "maximum number of iterations reached without convergence" error. You can extend that (e.g. `control = nlmeControl(maxIter = 1000)`), but I ran into more problems down the line ("step halving factor reduced below minimum"). You're likely to run into more and more computational issues as you make the model that complicated, unless you have very clean data ...

Comment: Thanks a lot once again, Ben. It works! It was surprising to not see "MINUTES" listed in "fixed =....". If I may, do you have any thoughts about weather this model or splines with two linear equations or splines with 1 linear + 1 quadratic would be a better fit? Thank you.

Comment: `MINUTES` is a covariate, not a parameter.  `fixed` is about the variation of *parameters* across groups/with respect to covariates (i.e., linear submodels for the parameters). I don't have strong feelings about the model - seems context-dependent. But this seems reasonable.